# If url is remotely or directly accessed php

Tags: php, url

What I'm asking is; 
How can I check if the url: `/u-dhs73jfjdj.jpg` `(/u.php?f=dhs73jfjdj.jpg)` is **directly or remotely loaded**?

I want to load a "landing page" with html and the image embedded etc if the URL is directly loaded.

And if not directly loaded, lets say the url is loaded from a `img tag` or anything, from some website I want the `u.php?f=` to return headers as the actual file.

Sorry if my English is bad, learned the language from google and mmo games ;p

Thank you for your time.

Comment: There's a reason why large web services such as `imgur` use a `i.` infront of `imgur.com` to serve just the image and otherwise to see the full html. this allows them to distinguish services by checking if the `%{HTTP_REQUEST} ^i.` which makes for rapid deployment without all of the hassle you're experiencing currently.

Comment: Yeah but i want one URL for both remote embedding and showing the image in a landing page with html etc.

Answer (score 0):

I was also experiencing this problem, the exact same thing actually.. We are making a website([link](http://www.lensert.com/7ob.png)) it's just a project to learn some more web development, and we also didn't want 2 links, maybe this will help:

What I did is:

Get the referer

- When referer is empty, it's probably typed in address bar.
- When referer contains lensert, it is linked on our site.
- And everything else is most likely from another site.

Code:

```
    $ref = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']: "";
    $im = imagecreate(350, 30);

    $bg = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
    $textcolor = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 255);

    if($ref == "")
    {
    imagestring($im, 5, 0, 0, 'Trough site or typed in address bar!', $textcolor);
    }
    else if (strpos($ref,'lensert.com')===false)
    {
    imagestring($im, 5, 0, 0, 'Other domain: '.$ref.'!', $textcolor);
    }
    else
    {
    imagestring($im, 5, 0, 0, 'Trough site or typed in address bar!', $textcolor);
    }
    header('Content-type: image/png');
    imagepng($im);
    imagedestroy($im);

    ?>
```

P.S Sorry for adding question instead of comment before.. But i think it was deleted anyway